# matplotlib - making labels for violin plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

I usually make labels for bars in the following manner using parameter 'label' in the method 'bar'.

```
axes[0].bar(x, y, bar_width, label='abc')
axes[0].legend()
```

Now I'd like to plot violin plots and make label for each collection as follows, but it doesn't work since 'violinplot' doesn't have the parameter 'label'.

```
axes[0].violinplot(data1, label='abc1')
axes[1].violinplot(data2, label='abc2')
```

Can anyone help me out to make a label for each collection?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#proxy-legend-handles

Comment: @PaulH Thank you for the link. Now I understand a little bit about legends.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it was mentioned in comment, some plots in matplotlib don't support legends. Documentation still provides a simple way to add custom legends for them: http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#proxy-legend-handles

Main idea : add 'fake' objects, which can be not shown in the plot, then use it to form a handles list for legend method.

```
    import random
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
    import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
    from itertools import repeat

    red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red')
    # 'fake' invisible object

    pos   = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]
    label = ['plot 1','plot2','ghi','jkl','mno','pqr']
    data  = [np.random.normal(size=100) for i in pos]

    fake_handles = repeat(red_patch, len(pos))

    pl.figure()
    ax = pl.subplot(111)
    pl.violinplot(data, pos, vert=False)
    ax.legend(fake_handles, label)
    pl.show()
```

[image: violinplot with custom legend]

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. I added fake handles as you told, and it seems work well. By the way, what does the parameter "label" in the method "Patch" do in your code? It seems to me nothing changes depending on the value.

Comment: @HanulLee, I fixed it (by removing). It is overriden in `legend` method call, that's why it changes nothing.

Answer (score 17):

Here is my solution for multple violin plots. Note that it grabs the patch color from the first shaded area of the given violin plot---this could be changed to do something else if there are multiple colors, or you could instead grab the color of the vertical bar with `violin["cbars"].get_color().flatten()`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import numpy as np

labels = []
def add_label(violin, label):
    color = violin["bodies"][0].get_facecolor().flatten()
    labels.append((mpatches.Patch(color=color), label))


positions = np.arange(3,13,3)
data = np.random.randn(1000, len(positions))
add_label(plt.violinplot(data, positions), "Flat")    

positions = np.arange(1, 10, 2)
data = np.random.randn(1000, len(positions)) + positions
add_label(plt.violinplot(data, positions), "Linear")

positions = np.arange(2, 11, 1)
data = np.random.randn(1000, len(positions)) + positions ** 2 / 4
add_label(plt.violinplot(data, positions), "Quadratic")

plt.legend(*zip(*labels), loc=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

There is an even simpler solution than @Ian Hincks code, without using `mpatches`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

positions = np.arange(3,13,3)
data = np.random.randn(1000, len(positions))
vp1 = plt.violinplot(data, positions) 

positions = np.arange(1, 10, 2)
data = np.random.randn(1000, len(positions)) + positions
vp2 = plt.violinplot(data, positions)

positions = np.arange(2, 11, 1)
data = np.random.randn(1000, len(positions)) + positions ** 2 / 4
vp3 = plt.violinplot(data, positions)

plt.legend([vp1['bodies'][0],vp2['bodies'][0], vp3['bodies'][0]], ['flat', 'linear', 'quadratic'], loc=2)[enter image description here][1]
```

To use the lines instead of the bodies replace `vp1['bodies'][0]` by `vp1['cbars']`

demo: [violin plot with labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1bxe.png)

Answer (score 5):

*edit: sorry, I now see that you wanted to add a legend, not axis labels...*

You can manually set the tick locations and then overwrite their labels:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

pos   = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]
label = ['abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno','pqr']
data  = [np.random.normal(size=100) for i in pos]

pl.figure()
ax = pl.subplot(111)
pl.violinplot(data, pos, vert=False)
ax.set_yticks(pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(label)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. As you mentioned already, I was looking for the way to add a legend. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

A leaner and clear solution can be:

```
plt.style.use('seaborn')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
labels = ['df=9' , 'df=99', 'df=999', 'df=9999', 'N($\mu=0$, $\sigma=2)$']
colors = ['orange', 'lightblue', 'lightgreen', 'yellow', 'green']
def make_violinplot(x, labels, colors):
    parts = plt.violinplot(x, showmeans=True, showmedians=True)
    for body, color in zip(parts['bodies'],colors):
        body.set_facecolor(color)
        parts['cmeans'].set_color('red')
        parts['cmedians'].set_color('blue')
    plt.legend(label[enter image description here][1]s, loc='upper left')
    plt.xticks(np.arange(1, len(labels)+1), labels)
    plt.title("probability density plots t- vs normal distribution")
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [8,8]
    return
make_violinplot(t_dists, labels, colors)
```